# Не работает move_uploaded_file

Tags: php

Содержимое index.php

```
<?php
    print_r($_FILES);
    ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '1M');
    $date = date('d.m.Y_H:i:s');
    $file = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "upl" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $date . "_" . $_FILES["inputfile"]["name"];
    $tmp = $_FILES["inputfile"]["tmp_name"];
    echo $file . "<br>";
    echo $tmp;
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $file))
    {
        echo "Work";
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Secure File Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Secure File Upload</h1>
        <form method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="inputfile">Upload File</label>
            <input type="file" id="inputfile" name="inputfile"></br>
            <input type="submit" value="Click To Upload">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Пишет в логах:

> [12-May-2018 22:28:00 Asia/Kuwait] **PHP Warning**:  move_uploaded_file():
>   Unable to move 'C:\Upload\php89F0.tmp' to
>   'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\file\upl\test.jpg' in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\file\index.php on line 9

Comment: У вас есть такая папка `wwwroot` ?

Comment: Совет на все случаи жизни – читайте внимательно логи и ошибки

Comment: Папка есть  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\

Comment: Если filename не является загруженным файлом, никаких действий не предпринимается и move_uploaded_file() возвращает FALSE.

Если filename является загруженным файлом, но не может быть перемещён по каким-либо причинам, никаких действий не предпринимается и move_uploaded_file() возвращает FALSE. Кроме того, отображается предупреждение. http://php.net/manual/ru/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: move_uploaded_file() не перемещает файл

Comment: папка назначения указана неверно, либо доступа на запись в эту папку нету для веб-сервера

Comment: Я думаю нет доступа, но как его открыть?

Comment: в конфигах для веб-сервака смотри

Comment: А именно в конфигах чего?

Comment: либо доступ к папке поменяй. Найди мануал в инете как работать с твоим веб-сервером на Windows